# How can I group this data without using LAG function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the dataset shown below. From this, I want to select the first row from each group where the PersonIDs status has changed to a different status than the previous one.

For example, from this dataset, I would want the rows 1, 4, 7 and 11.
Any help on this?
If I do a GROUPBY, it just lumps together all New and all Pending in 2 groups. I only have SQL server 2008, so the lag function won't work.

```
PersonID    Status  WhenChanged
101         New     27/01/2017 15:27
101         New     27/01/2017 16:40
101         New     27/01/2017 16:40
101         Pending 27/01/2017 16:40
101         Pending 27/01/2017 16:40
101         Pending 27/01/2017 16:40
101         New     31/01/2017 09:14
101         New     31/01/2017 10:02
101         New     31/01/2017 10:03
101         New     31/01/2017 10:05
101         Pending 03/02/2017 14:29
101         Pending 03/02/2017 14:29
```

Comment: Is your `WhenChanged` seriously a `VARCHAR` value...?

Comment: With your structure, this is impossible.  Your datetime values (which look suspiciously like a `VARCHAR`) are *not* unique.  You have nothing to sort on.  And without anything to order these results by, there is no guaranteed order of your results.  Thus, making it impossible to get the results you want.  You need a unique id for the records.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a difference of `row_numbers()` and then another `row_number()`:

```
select PersonID, Status, WhenChanged
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by personid, status, seqnum_p - seqnum_ps
                                order by whenchanged
                               ) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by personid order by whenchanged) as seqnum_p,
                   row_number() over (partition by personid, status order by whenchanged) as seqnum_ps
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

To understand how this works, I would suggest that you run the subqueries and look at the results.  The difference between these row numbers defines the groups.

An alternative is to use `outer apply`.  However, the above probably has better performance.